# Find the innermost square matrix of a square matrix using recursion

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, matrix, multidimensional-array

The question asks me that given any square matrix, I need to find the innermost square matrix using a recursive function.

Here is my python code:

```
def findInnerMatrix(matrix):
    for i in range(0, len(matrix)): 
        for j in range(0, len(matrix)):
            if len(matrix) % 2 != 0: #if matrix is odd
                while len(matrix) > 1 and len(matrix[i]) > 1: #del elements until 1 element left
                    del matrix[i][j]
            if len(matrix) % 2 == 0: #if length of matrix is even
                while len(matrix) > 2 and len(matrix[i]) > 2: #del el until 2 rows of 2 el left
                    del matrix[i][j] 
    return matrix
```

And... I haven't really figured out the logic yet so I don't know how to write it recursively either.

Given this input:

```
[[9, 13, 5, 2],
 [1, 11, 7, 6],
 [3, 7, 4, 1],
 [6, 0, 7, 10]]
```

It's giving me an output of:
[[5, 2], [7, 6], [4, 1], [7, 10]]
The desired output is:
[[11, 7], [7, 4]] #the middle two elements from the middle two matrices

Comment: I don't understand why iteration or recursion is required for this. It's like being asked to calculate the half of an integer and use recursion for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_innermost_square(matrix):
    # Base case: when the matrix is 1x1 or empty
    if len(matrix) <= 1:
        return matrix

    # Remove the first and last row
    matrix = matrix[1:-1]

    # Remove the first and last column
    matrix = [row[1:-1] for row in matrix]

    # Recursive call
    return get_innermost_square(matrix)

# Example usage:
matrix = [[1, 2, 3, 4], 
          [5, 6, 7, 8], 
          [9, 10, 11, 12], 
          [13, 14, 15, 16]]

print(get_innermost_square(matrix))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually easier to express recursively.  If the square matrix is larger than 2x2, recurse with one row and column removed on every side (i.e. skip first and last column and skip first and last row):

```
def innerMat(M):
    return M if len(M)<=2 else innerMat([r[1:-1] for r in M[1:-1]])
```

output:

```
m = [[9, 13, 5, 2],
     [1, 11, 7, 6],
     [3, 7, 4, 1],
     [6, 0, 7, 10]]

print(*innerMat(m),sep="\n")

[11, 7]
[7, 4]
```